# Detect window inactivity in Java

Tags: java, swing, timer

How do I detect inactivity in a window (including it's dialog boxes) and then use a javax.swing.Timer to measure for X amount of time the window has been inactive and then println a message ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Application Inactivity](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/) might help you out.